# Best storage option for temporary data

Tags: relational-database, storage, nosql

In the context of an application I am developing I need to store quite a good amount of data for limited amount of time - think of the scenario in terms of object buckets - for a certain limited amount of time objects are in some buckets then they move to others and others... and so on. There is basically a n to m relation between objects (order of millions) and buckets (thousands to maybe tens of thousands)

It is important for this storage layer to be persistent so that, in case of app / server failure, I can recreate the last state.

What would the best option be for implementing such temporary storage

- A relational SGBD - we are currently using PostgreSQL, would it be an
  option? I am mainly concern about its capacity to respond to such a
  usage scenario. Would another SGBD be an option ?
- A NOSQL persistence provider - I am thinking mainly at Redis for the
  impressive write / read speed but other DBs, not necessarily from the
  Key-Value family might also be OK.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an object can only belong to one bucket at a time then this should fit well with Postgres - you'd just need a `buckets` table with a set of unique bucket identifiers, and then the objects' tables would have a `currentbucket` column to indicate the bucket to which they currently belong.

If an object can belong to an unbounded number of buckets then you can still use Postgres, but you'll need to remove the `currentbucket` column from the objects' tables and instead have a `bucketobjectjoin` table with a column for bucket identifier and a column for object identifier.  Since you're already using Postgres I'd recommend implementing it this way as a first pass.  If you're not happy with the performance then you can cache the `bucketobjectjoin` table in Redis (as a `Set` of bucket identifiers keyed to an object identifier, and/or as a `Set` of object identifiers keyed to a bucket identifier) - you're only storing the objects' keys (not the full objects) in Redis so memory shouldn't be an issue, and you can have a background task occasionally sync Redis with Postgres's `bucketobjectjoin` table in case the Redis server crashes.

As a full blown nosql approach you can use Cassandra to store the full objects; Cassandra supports `Set`s like Redis does, but doesn't have Redis's memory restrictions.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking the same way. Do you see any reason why a relational database won't hold in such scenario? I somehow feel PostgreSQL doesn't quite fit into the picture but can't find any benchmarks to prove me either right or wrong.

Comment: @AdrianFlorea If you have very sparse objects, e.g. they potentially have thousands of properties but over 90% of these are null, then a columnar database like Cassandra may be a better option because it doesn't allocate disk space for the nulls.  Also, if you're basically treating the temporary data as though it were a queue then you might be better off using a queueing/messaging service that persists its messages in case of a server crash, e.g. [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)

Answer (score 1):

We used to keep temporary data in our SQL Server, but then we moved to memcached and we could see big performance improvements - mainly because that data is in memory and not on disk. And starting from last year we are only using Redis, which has some more advantages, like more types supported or no need to break those objects due to size limitation. 
So if your data is big and changes a lot and it is also temporary then I suggest redis. And you can have a redis cluster of 1 master and 2 slaves and that will provide you the HA you are looking for.